# Printing elements in arrays only once and each on a new line

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I'm trying to print all the elements in an array in a new line.

however when I'm trying to print, it comes up like this: (example)

```
array = [1,2,3,4];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

prints:

```
1,

1,2,

1,2,3,

1,2,3,4,
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You'd better provide the actual code you are using

Comment: it print `1\n
2\n
3\n
4\n` correct result

Answer (score 0):

> However when I'm trying to print, it comes up like this

No, it doesn't. Your code hardly matches the output you're giving. You make an array by `[]` instead of `{}`, and you're output gives a `,`, which is nowhere to be seen in your code.

The Output you're mentioning is incorrect, the code runs as it should, producing output :

```
1
2
3
4
```

Runs [here](http://ideone.com/iFxyxr)

Answer (score -1):

User Arrays.toString

```
int[]  array = {1,2,3,4};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: OP is trying to print each element on a separate line.

Answer (score -1):

this answers your specific question:

```
 int[] array = {1,2,3,4};
               for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
               System.out.print(array[i]);
               System.out.print(" ");

               }
```

Comment: OP is trying to print each element on a separate line.